# How to use the SpriteKit method body(at : CGPoint)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have game that during the game your finger moves around and should avoid hitting some obstacles. I know how to use collision but I recently heard that there is a funtion called the `body(at : point)`.
I should say that I have masked my obstacles. Because of that I can't use the `contains(point)` function. 
I really want to use the `body(at : point)` function otherwise I know how to work with collisions.

Some of my code:

```
play_button = self.childNode(withName: "play_button") as! SKSpriteNode
for t in touches{
    let fingerlocation = t.location(in: self)
    if physicsworld.body(at : fingerlocation)
    {
        let so = level6(fileNamed:"level6")
        so?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(so!, transition: 
        SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1))
    }
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

physicsworld.body returns an SKPhysicsBody if found, so you just need to check if it exists

`if let _ = physicsworld.body(at : fingerlocation)`

If your goal is to make a button, then I would not do this approach.

I would recommend just subclassing SKSpriteNode and enabling the isUserInteractionEnable`

```
class Button : SKSpriteNode
{

   override init()
   {
     super.init()
     isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   }
   //then in your touchesBegan/touchesEnded code (wherever you placed it)
   ....
   let so = level6(fileNamed:"level6")
        so?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.view?.presentScene(so!, transition: 
        SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1))
   ....
}
```

Comment: i want to use the body( at :  point) beacuse  am a newbie and i don't know how to use the subclass
so if possible please give me a sample code in order to use the body( at : point ).
and as i said i want to do that certain action when the user touches the masked area of that sprite or button

Comment: Then you dont have a physicsbody where you are touching

Comment: do you mean this **(if let _ = physicsworld.body(at : fingerlocation))**

Comment: what should i do to get a physicsbody??

Comment: i have masked my button that i want to click on

Comment: I am not going to give you all the answers, I am sorry.  If you do not know what a physics body is then you have no business dealing with the physics world.  You can google every term you do not understand and find out what they are.  Find some tutorials and carefully read through them.

Comment: sorry my friend the action works when i put your code but still when i click on the unmasked area the action will be done

Comment: please answer me i am not a pro developer i am just 13 years old and coding for game

Comment: i searched the whole web but i did not find anything

Comment: You really need to find a tutorial then, one that can speak to a brand new coder like yourself.  I do not know of any tutorials

Comment: okay then how should i use the peice of code that you game to me

Comment: i don't think that a hard question

Comment: You don't. You find a tutorial so you can understand what you are writing.  You need to crawl before you can walk.

Comment: i have already used collision but then my code is very heavy when i found out that there is a function i really wanted to use that

Comment: If you have a public library go ask a librarian for a book dealing with programming.

Comment: i know but there is no tutorial regrding my question on the web
please help

Comment: you know because i live in iran the programing resources are very less

Comment: You do not know why you are using that function, I am done here, go find some tutorials, stack overflow is not the place for your experience yet.

Comment: you mean you are not going to help!!??

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, "if let body = physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation){...}" was responding wherever I've touched the screen.

I figured out, that by default the SKScene object created its own SKPhysicsBody which was set on top of all other SKPhysicsBodies.
I solved this problem by making a new SKPhysicsBody for the scene, which didn't interfere anymore. Hope this code will help you.

inside of didMove:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
borderBody.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = borderBody
```