# body(at :point) spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a button that I only want to touch the masked part on the screen but when I use this code even when I touch at the part that is not masked and not visible it does the action here's my code

```
// Spaceship 4: physics body using texture’s alpha channel
let texturedSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
texturedSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
spaceShipTexture, size: CGSize(width: circularSpaceShip.size.width,                                                      
height:circularSpaceShip.size.height))
if let _ physicsworld.body(at : fingerlocation){
  //do the action I want
}
```

I should say that I have not created a `skphysics` body for this to work 
please tell me how to make a `skphysicbody` in order for this to work 
i created

Comment: you dont know how to create any physicsbody?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the SpriteKit method body(at : CGPoint)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200968/how-to-use-the-spritekit-method-bodyat-cgpoint)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions

Comment: i think i know but as knight0fdragon says i don't so can you tell me?